# Next.js Showing Images Render Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

**Problem:** I'm attempting to render a react component that `<Gallery images={images} />`, and whilst the component shows, the images in the array do not. When changing the screen size by dragging the console window, the images load.

**Component:**

```
<ImageListItem key={item} position="relative">
  <Image
    lazyBoundary="100px"
    placeholder="blur"
    blurDataURL="/loading-image.jpg"
    onClick={() => openLightbox(i)}
    style={{
      filter: theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? "brightness(0.7)" : "none",
      cursor: "pointer",
      borderRadius: 8,
    }}
    layout="fill"
    src={item}
    alt={"Job Listing"}
  />
</ImageListItem>
```

The parent child relationships are:

1. CareerOpening -> Main
2. Main -> Gallery

**Steps for Images Loading in CareerOpening.js:**

Retrieve the job listing by waiting for `id` of `useRouter()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    id && retrieveJobListingInformation();
  }, [id]);
```

When the job listing is available, use the values within it to get the jobs. The `listJobListingImages` looks at an array, maps over it, and pushes `Blobs` into it:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getLogo();
    retrieveEmployerInformation();
    listJobListingImages();
  }, [jobListingInformation]);
```

The state is then passed in as props to the component, `<Main />`, and then `<Main />` passes it to `<Gallery/>`

**Note:** The `<Gallery />` component logs the images correctly, and this proves they're being passed correctly.

**EDIT:** Changing the `<Image/>` tag to `<img/>` still showed the same issues.

Comment: Does this question need more information? Let me know!

Comment: Were you using the lazy attribute when you seitched to ```<img>``` tag?

Comment: I did not. One solution I've put in place is this:
`useEffect(() => {setTimeout(() => {setLoadingImages(false)}, 3000)}, [])`

I show a loading spinner now when it is loading, and after 3 seconds the images appear... This was done in the Gallery component

Comment: Can you provide a code sandbox for this? I tried recreating the same but I think I might be missing something. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-xe45fx?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by changing how the images were obtained, by waiting for all the images to download with `promise.all()`.

**Before Code:**

```
export const getJobImagesFromS3 = async (images: Array<string>, identityId: string): Promise<string[]> => {
  let imageArray = [];
  images.map(async (item) => {
    try {
      const image =  await Storage.get(item, {
        level: "protected",
        identityId: identityId,
        download: true,
        cacheControl: "no-cache",
      })
      imageArray.push(URL.createObjectURL(image["Body"] as Blob))
      return imageArray;
    } catch(error) {
      console.error("images.map", error);
      imageArray.push(null)
    }
  })
  return imageArray;
}
```

**After Code:**

```
export const getJobImagesFromS3 = async (images: Array<string>, identityId: string): Promise<string[]> => {
  let imageArray = [];
  const promises = images.map(async (item) => {
    try {
      const image = await Storage.get(item, {
        level: "protected",
        identityId: identityId,
        download: true,
        cacheControl: "no-cache",
      });
      imageArray.push(URL.createObjectURL(image["Body"] as Blob));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("images.map", error);
      imageArray.push(null);
    }
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);
  return imageArray;
};
```

`promise.all()` is recommended in such cases is because it helps to wait for all the promises to resolve before returning the results, thereby ensuring that all the asynchronous operations have completed.